# Sequence Numbers for ID in Mongo DB

Tags: php, mongodb, database, nosql

There is findAndModify command in Mongo DB to use auto increment numbers instead of the default ID, but I do not know how to use it for PHP driver (I am not sure if it is supported at all).

Comment: It is hard to generate incremental ids in distributed environment. I suggest to use unique generated ids, like objectId instead of incremental.

Comment: The problem is that I want to use them for web articles, and the long ID will be part of my url which is not good at all. This is the reason that I wish to use sql-like auto_increment primary_key

Comment: Mb this post -> http://shiflett.org/blog/2010/jul/auto-increment-with-mongodb will help you. But i think that objectId look okay even in url ;)

Comment: @Andrew How is this hard? findAndModify provides the tool that does this perfectly on a distributed environment. Whether or not it's a good idea is a bit up for debate. I'd prefer OIDs too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, if you need to store incremental values i suggest you do it using some other field not the mongodb _id field mongodb used these generated id's to return some (i believe many if not all) types of queries, especially if you have a multi cluster set up then it definitely uses the _id field to locate the physical disk the data is on (i believe using a hash table or some such technology - not entirely up to date with the under the hood operations of mongo's kernel). In short, please leave this alone its designed to be an auto generated reference field.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$m = new MongoClient();

// select a database
$db = $m->seq;

// select a collection (analogous to a relational database's table)
$collection = $db->counters;
$user_collection = $db->user;



/**********Function to auto increment seq************/
function getNextSequence($name){
global $collection;

$retval = $collection->findAndModify(
     array('_id' => $name),
     array('$inc' => array("seq" => 1)),
     null,
     array(
        "new" => true,
    )
);
return $retval['seq'];
}

$db_array=array('_id' => getNextSequence("userid"), 'name' => 'debojit');

$user_collection->insert($db_array);
```